# How to always show bottom bar over popup virtual keyboard

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I am using Delphi XE 8 to build Android app and I have a form that have two buttons at the bottom like this one

[image]

How I make sure these buttons still visible when the virtual keyboard appear and position back to the bottom when the keyboard disappear ?, effect would be like this screen:

[image]

Comment: Windows, Mac, iOS or Android? What controls are we looking at?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the missing details. Frankly you should know how to do this by now.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the virtual keyboard always covers the bottom area. Almost all mobile apps (iOS and Android) have such buttons on the top. Not saying it's impossible, just not common. You should consider making your app follow the common practice of most other apps on the market.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes I am trying to follow the standard, the pictures above are from Android KitKat, from Settings, Security, Pin Menu so it should be standard ? also can you give a picture link to know what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at Embarcadero example: [FMX.Mobile.ScrollableForm Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE8/en/FMX.Mobile.ScrollableForm_Sample)
and add an extra TLayout with bottom buttons (cancel/continue) - the position of this layout should be assigned according to bounds from VirtualKeyboardShown event handler. There is also another, similar example called KeyboardToolbar. The examples can be also found in "c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Samples\User Interface\"

Comment: In KeyboardToolbar I found it is not possible to add Android as a target, how they do that ?

Comment: I believe that it is hardcoded somethere in *.proj file. Recreating the project from pure *.dpr *.pas *.fmx allows to add Android target. But the readme states: "the virtual keyboard service is not available for Android devices". So this example is only for ios mobile target. You should follow the ScrollableForm solution.